# Setting UITableView's Frame Does Not Work Correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, frame

I have a view controller that has a tableView in it. When I set the frame of it's tableView, it appears on the screen at a different place then the frame that I gave it. For example, giving it an X coord of 200 with a width of 128 puts the whole thing off the screen.

Here is where I instantiate the view controller:

```
myPopover = [[PopupVC alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 47, 128, 150)];
```

And the init code for the view controller:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)_frame
{
    self = [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self)
    {
        frame = _frame;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setFrame:frame];
    staticTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.view addSubview:staticTable];
```

}

Does anybody know why this is happening? When logging the frame, it says exactly what I entered, but this is obviously not the frame that is being put on the view. As another test, I made a view of the exact same dimensions which clearly showed that they are in different places. Very weird, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I just had a thought, could it have to do with the fact that I am using viewdidload instead of load view when I don't have a nib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your

[self.view setFrame:frame];

(100,47) absolute coordinate

```
|                |
|                |
|   self.view    |
|                |
|                |
```

you staticTable leave zero coordinates.

```
staticTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,128,150) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

because

(0,0) relative coordinate for self.view.

(100,47) absolute coordinate for superView

```
self.view
    |[                ]|
    |[                ]|
    |[staticTableView ]|
    |[                ]|
    |[                ]|
```

If you set the frame is equal to the image below.

```
staticTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

---

```
self.view
 |      [      |         ]
 |      [      |         ]
 |      [static|TableView]
 |      [      |         ]
 |      [      |         ]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a great reminder for something simple that I forgot.

Answer (score 1):

the myPopover width is 128 and height is 150

so how can add table view with x cordinate with 200 it must be below 128 to show the table . frame is cordinates regarding the subView but not the totall view of the screen.